# How to loop through the index of a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write to a file, with the first line being [0] in the list, 2nd line being [1], etc.

Here's a quick example

```
crimefile = open('C:\states.csv', 'r')
b = crimefile.read()
l = b.splitlines()
print l[1]

states = open('c:\states.txt', 'w')
states.write('"abc"' + " " + '%s' '\n' %l[0+=])

states.close()
```

I'm really new to loops in Python and I am not too sure about loops and how to increase integers during loops, basically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `enumerate()`:

```
for ind,line in enumerate(l):
    print ind,line
```

example:

```
In [55]: lis=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
In [57]: for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    print i,x
   ....:     
   ....:     
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```

or using `len()` and `xrange()`:

```
In [59]: for i in xrange(len(lis)):     #use range() in case of python 3.x
   ....:     print i,lis[i]
   ....:     
   ....:     
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
```

Comment: Of course, this and many other use cases don't actually need `enumerate` -- you can just use `for line in l: ...`.

Comment: Ooh ok over my head... I'm not gonna ask anymore questions though, just going to dissect that. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I got your question, but this is how i would solve it anyhow:

```
f = open('C:\states.csv', 'r')
states = open('c:\states.txt', 'w')

for line in f:
    states.write('"abc"  %s\n' % line)

f.close()
states.close()
```

Comment: you could improve this solution by using the `with open(<filename>) as file` context manager syntax, then you wouldn't have to worry about explicitly close the file

Comment: i thinkkk you solved it a bit more eloquently, so thanks :) quick question, why the %(seemingly instead of a single quote) before the newline after the string in the argument on line 5?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that was a typo, I've fixed that. Also since your string seems to be -"abc" [thevalue]\n- I see no point in separating the string into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

This is the 'pythonic' solution:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
with open('outfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(l))
```

I am not sure about your `'abc'` stuff, but considering you need that, this would be a solution:

```
'\n'.join(['"abc" %s' % e for e in l])
```

Comment: One often-overlooked issue when using `'\n'.join` is that you don't get the `\n` character at the end, on the last line.  Once or twice that's broken a processing tool which wasn't as robust as it should have been.